# Money-Rails Gem: How to make a select list for all currencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, money-rails

I'm using the [money-rails gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails) and want to show in my view a list of different currencies but the code I have now isn't working.

I have my `Price` model and the fields `in_cents` and `currency`:

```
create_table :prices do |t|
  t.integer :in_cents, default: 0, null: false
  t.string :currency, default: 'USD', null: false
```

Now according to the [Money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) and Money-Rails docs I had to do something like:

```
class Price < ActiveRecord::Base

  monetize :in_cents, as: "amount", with_model_currency: :in_cents_currency

  def all_currencies(hash)
    hash.keys
  end
```

Than my view with simple form gem:

```
= f.input :currency, collection: all_currencies(Money::Currency.table)
= f.input :amount, required: false
```

But this gives me the error:

```
undefined method `all_currencies' for #<#<Class:0xd154124>:0xd15bab4>
```

Why?

P.S.

I want to show the ISO Code and the name like `United States Dollar (USD)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your all_currencies method is an instance method, and you're not calling it on an instance.

Add `self.all_currencies`, and then call it with `Price.all_currencies`

Hope this helps

Comment: Not sure why this throws me a `Wrong Number of Arguments` error.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Had to do `Price.all_currencies(Money::Currency.table)`. This does have all the iso_codes but not in the format that I'm looking for. There all lowercase like `usd` and without the name of the currency. You know how I could do `United States Dollar (USD)`?

Comment: You are passing in Money::Currency.table as the argument to self.all_currencies and calling keys which is returning lowercase currency abbreviations. I don't know what keys/values are stored in Money::Currency.table, but try replacing hash.keys with hash.values, or better yet, inspect the hash and see if there are other keys you can call to give you the desired output.

Comment: Easier to just do  Money::Currency.table.keys instead of creating an all_currencies method on the model.

Answer (score 16):

Not sure this is the best solution however I made a helper as such:

```
  def currency_codes
    currencies = []
    Money::Currency.table.values.each do |currency|
      currencies = currencies + [[currency[:name] + ' (' + currency[:iso_code] + ')', currency[:iso_code]]]
    end
    currencies
  end
```

Comment: How about `Money::Currency.table.values.map {} `

Answer (score 5):

Most simple solution:

```
= f.select :currency, Money::Currency.table
```